# why paypal IPN simulator returning INVALID?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am trying for Hour to integrate Paypal Watched lot of Tutorials on Youtube and but haven't solved my problem yet ,even in stack overflow there are similar question available but none of them works for me The Paypal IPN always return INVALID Please help..

here is My   listener.php

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cmd=_notify-validate&" . http_build_query($_POST));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents("test.txt", $response);
```

some ppl suggest me to change payment_date and set it to null or blank i tried too but this is also don't work for me.

thanks!

Comment: Please show what are you sending via POST - `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: i am using paypal IPN simulator to post data or where shd i use this?

Comment: Well, if you started approaching the problem with understanding and not trying to copypaste a piece of code that "works", you might get somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I never used to get this issue but had to make some changes to my code and was using the IPN Testing tool and started to get the invalid message rather than a successful email notification. Even though my code was using the urldecode & urlencode to get and send correctly the test tool would fail however a live IPN would succeed!!!
Some of my code:

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
```

So in order to get around getting the invalid message in the test tool at the bottom of the form tick "Show All", find the auction_closing_date which will have a value like "Sat Mar 23 2019 09:34:11 GMT+0000" and replace the "+" after the GMT in my case with a space and this will allow you to use the IPN tool successfully or at least it did  in my case. Good luck